# How to write a Class for retrieving IEnumerable Objects in EF and C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, class, webforms

I use c# asp.net 4 web forms and ef4.

In my Code Behind I use several times this code below to bind and rebind (for refresh) e GridView after an insertion or other operations completed using EF objects.

Using a simple gridview.DataBind(); does not work because I call EF programmatically so I thought to use a Class to keep in memory this code that can create Objects for my GridView  and call it how many time I need in my code avoiding redundancy.

```
IEnumerable<CmsContent> queryContents = 
    myCurrentSlot.CmsContents.Where(x => x.IsPublished == true);

uxManageContents.DataSource = queryContents;
uxManageContents.DataBind();
```

Can you help me to write this Class? Or do you know a batter way to Refresh the gridview after EF executing some commands? how to do it?

Please remember that I do use any data source web control for the gridview but i bind it programmatically.

Comment: Call the databind only once and your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [ObjectDataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9a4kyhcx.aspx) instead of codebehind.